# numpy.fft.rfft producing NaNs

Tags: numpy, fft

I'm just trying to learn a bit about FFTs and a bit about the Jupyter/iPython notebook. I have a few time series data sets. With most of them, numpy.fft.rfft produces a nice set of amplitudes. With one data set, it produces nothing but NaNs. The data set looks okay to me:

[image: some time series data]

Here's one it was completely happy with:

[image]

Both have just over 40k data points. Is there some way to get numpy.fft.rfft to tell me what it doesn't like about my data set instead of just producing output full of NaNs?

Comment: I figured out that my data set had one or more holes, so I can work on that. I'd still like to know if it's possible to get the FFT functions to complain about bad/missing/unexpected values.

Comment: No  [what you see is what you get](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). These functions are relatively thin wrappers around optimized libraries ([Fortran FFTPACK in Numpy’s case](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/fft/fftpack.py#L29-L30)) which don’t hold your hand. [`numpy.isfinite`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) will help you.